# MySQL: Any way to SELECT increment a number except using + operator

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Query is simple

```
SELECT count(ID)+1 from money_receipt;
```

The web api I'm using '+' sign used to define relationship between tables, so it returns an error. Althought - * / are working perfectly. Meanwhile I'm not allowed to change the api file. 
So is there any alternative of + operator like any functions to add two numbers in MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: does't the api define any escape character for that symbol?

Comment: I need to figure it out, there should be...

Comment: Another way you can try is writing a function that adds two numbers and call it from the select.

Comment: Api limits many scopes like custom funtions here. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: +Juan, it's web encoding code %2B for +, Now it's all working... Such a stupid I am...
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `UNION` query with `SELECT 1` and do a `SUM()`

```
SELECT SUM(ID) as ID FROM (
    SELECT count(ID) as ID from money_receipt
    UNION
    SELECT 1
) a
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6a92/7

Comment: I was trying, just found the same thing a moment ago  
SELECT count(*)  FROM (SELECT ID from money_receipt UNION SELECT 0 ) Counter